# How to validate if email is already taken using Lumen?

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I am new to Lumen (Laravel). I want to validate if email is already taken by following the Lumen documentation .

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|unique:borrower|max:255',
        //'mobile' => 'required|unique:borrower|max:255'

    ]);
```

If I execute the following line in postman, it shows like 422 unprocessed entity.

How can I check if email is already taken through Lumen and show the error message in view? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please always consult documentation before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Inserting new entry

```
function validateUser($request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'bail|required|email|unique:borrower,email',
    ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

For Updating

```
function validateUser($request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'bail|required|email|unique:borrower,email,'.$request->id.',id',
    ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

Combining both

```
function validateUser($request){
    $id = isset($request->id) ? ','.$request->id.',id':'';
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'bail|required|email|unique:borrower,email'.$id,
    ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

After that you can pass `$validator` to display all error.

Bail : `bail` checks first condition, if fails it will not check for email valiation or unique checks.

Answer (score 3):

Is `borrower` your table name that email should be unique in?

According to the docs:

> **unique:table,column,except,idColumn**
>
> The field under validation must be unique on a given database table.
>   If the `column` option is not specified, the field name will be used.
>
> **Specifying A Custom Column Name:**
>
> ```
> 'email' => 'unique:users,email_address'
> ```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Ya, borrower is table name

Comment: And is `email` the field name?

Comment: email is the field name

Comment: Have a look in `storage/logs/` at the log files then, must be something else going on in your code.

Comment: As per the https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique)document i edited my code and executed in postman and it show response like **{
  "email": [
    "The email has already been taken."
  ]
}** .

Comment: how to convert response message to json message.